# Проблема с циклом while true в python'e

Tags: python, while

```py
import random
from random import choice
key = input('Добро пожалвать ' '\n\nЖелайте сыграть ?')
if key in ('да' 'угу'  'Да' 'естественно'  'конечно'):

    while True:
        balance = 1
        print('ваш баланс ' + str(balance))
        qq = input('еще ?')
        if qq == ('да'):
            res = random.choices([1,2], weights= [50,50])
            print(res)
            if res == 1:
                balance + 1
                print('ура теперь твой баланс' + str(balance))
            elif res == 2:
                print('ну все ты проиграл твой баланс был' + str(balance))

        else:
            print('ты набрал целых ' + str(balance) + ' очков!!')
            break
else:
    print("отложим на попозже")
```

Всегда выводит просто 1 на балансе не прибавляет и даже если в `random.choices` выпадает 2 которое должно завершать игру все равно просто выводит баланс 1

Comment: Кстати, что у вас за ерунда с импортами? После того, как модуль импортировался (`import random`) зачем импортировать из него отдельную функцию? Во-первых это просто не получится, во-вторых зачем?

Comment: А ошибка, кстати, в строке `balance + 1`. Вы забыли вставить `=`. Нужно `balance += 1`.

Comment: спасибо вам большое только начал для себя учить пайтон первое что попробовал написать сам без чей то помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо так (я ещё и поправил правописание и стиль кода):

```py
import random
key = input('Добро пожаловать\n\nЖелаете сыграть? ')

balance = 1  # создаём переменную перед циклом

if key in ('да', 'угу', 'Да', 'естественно', 'конечно'):
    while True:
        print('ваш баланс ' + str(balance))
        qq = input('еще? ')
        if qq == 'да':
            # используем choice вместо choices (отличия см. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences)
            res = random.choice([1, 2])
            print(res)
            if res == 1:
                balance += 1  # изменяем существующую переменную
                print('ура теперь твой баланс ' + str(balance))
            elif res == 2:
                print('ну все, ты проиграл твой баланс был ' + str(balance))

        else:
            print('ты набрал целых ' + str(balance) + ' очков!!')
            break
else:
    print("отложим на попозже")
```

Comment: спасибо 2 вопрос я создал потому что несмотря на 2 ответа ни один не заработал

Comment: А этот-то работает?

Comment: @Genez1sPlay, если вам помог этот ответ, отметьте его как [**принятый**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (галка напротив ответа).

Comment: работает за пояснение отдельное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вот исправленный код:

```
import random
key = input('Добро пожаловать! \n\nЖелаете сыграть? ').lower()
good_answers = ['да', 'угу', 'естественно', 'конечно']
if key in good_answers:
    balance = 1
    while True:
        print('Ваш баланс — ' + str(balance))
        qq = input('Еще? ')
        if qq in good_answers:
            res = random.choices([1, 2])
            print("Выпало: ", res)
            if res == 1:
                balance += 1
                print('Ура, теперь твой баланс ' + str(balance))
            elif res == 2:
                print('Ну все, ты проиграл, твой баланс был' + str(balance))

        else:
            print('Ты набрал целых ' + str(balance) + ' очков!!!')
            break
else:
    print("Отложим на попозже")
```

Советую автору вопроса почитать PEP8. Тогда его код будет выглядеть лучше и в нем будет проще искать ошибки)

Comment: скопировал ваш код баланс все равно возвращается к 1 а если в res выпадает 2 то цикл просто начинается с начала

Comment: У строчки `balance = 1` что-то не так с отступами.

Comment: @wchistow, исправил.